# box2dweb beginner: can't simulate fixture added by clicking on canvas

Tags: javascript, box2d

I've just started playing around with box2dweb and have now run into a problem that is leaving me stumped.

I have a basic simulation with a "ground" static fixture and some code that allows me to add shapes (just circles for now) to the canvas at the point where I click on it.

My code is working in as far as I can add as many circles to the canvas as I want and have them drawn on the canvas.

I then have a button that begins the simulation by entering the step loop. I would expect that when I click the button, the circles would fall to the "ground" and eventually come to rest, thereby ending the simulation.

The problem is that as soon as I begin the simulation, the very next frame completely removes all the fixtures in the scene. However, if I start out with a circle in the scene (not added by click, but by the initialization function that creates the world and the ground), and I begin the simulation, it runs as expected: the circle drops at some rate and stops on the "ground".

I'm using the same function `addCircle()` to add the circle at either the initialization of the scene or when I click on the canvas, so it seems like that code is fine.

```js
// this function is called by the canvas onclick
function addShape(e) {
    var shape = $('input:radio[name=shape]:checked').val();
    var offset = $("#c").offset();

    if (shape == "circle") {
        addCircle((e.pageX - offset.left) / SCALE,
                  (e.pageY - offset.top) / SCALE,
                  $("#dimen").val());
    }
    gWorld.DrawDebugData();
}

// same function is used by the above handler and also to set up a circle
// in the initial scene, however when added via click, the simulation
// breaks (all objects disappear in the next frame)
function addCircle(x, y, r) {
    var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef;
    fixDef.density = 1.0;
    fixDef.friction = 0.5;
    fixDef.restitution = 0.2;

    var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.x = x;
    bodyDef.position.y = y;

    fixDef.shape = new b2CircleShape(r);
    gWorld.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);
}

// called when a button to start the simulation is clicked
function startSimulation() {
    gWorld.SetGravity(new b2Vec2(0, parseInt($("#gravity").val())));
    gStopped = false;
    requestAnimFrame(update);
}

// this is the main step loop
function update() {
    if (!gStopped) {

    gWorld.Step(
           1 / 60   //frame-rate
        ,  10       //velocity iterations
        ,  10       //position iterations
    );

    gWorld.DrawDebugData();
    gWorld.ClearForces();

    var keepGoing = true;
    for (var b = gWorld.GetBodyList(); keepGoing && b; b = b.m_next) {
        if (! b.IsAwake()) {
            keepGoing = false;
        }
    }
    if (keepGoing) {
        requestAnimFrame(update);
    }
}

function init() {
    gWorld = new b2World(
        new b2Vec2(0, parseInt($("#gravity").val())),
        true);

    var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef;
    fixDef.density = 1.0;
    fixDef.friction = 0.5;
    fixDef.restitution = 0.2;

    //create ground
    var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_staticBody;
    bodyDef.position.x = $("#c").width() / 2 / SCALE;
    bodyDef.position.y = $("#c").height() / SCALE;

    fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
    fixDef.shape.SetAsBox((600 / SCALE) / 2, (10/SCALE) / 2);
    gWorld.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);

    //setup debug draw
    var debugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
    debugDraw.SetSprite(document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d"));
    debugDraw.SetDrawScale(SCALE);
    debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.3);
    debugDraw.SetLineThickness(1.0);
    debugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit | b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);
    gWorld.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);

    // this circle is simulated correctly
    addCircle(1,1,1);

    gWorld.DrawDebugData();
}
```

Comment: If you check the position and velocity of the missing bodies, might give us a hint about what happened to them (GetPosition and GetLinearVelocity)

Comment: I'll check it tonight after work and come back with the result. What's most interesting however, is that the ground fixture also disappears, and it's attached to a static body!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that the problem was in lines like these:

```js
$("#dimen").val()
```

When I changed this to the following, the simulation began to run as normal:

```js
parseFloat($("#dimen").val())
```

Answer (score 1):

Box2DWeb seriously lack documentation, Been breaking my head over it. Figured out some of the basic workflows, have blogged about it in here http://box2dinabox.blogspot.in/ . hope you will find it useful :)

Comment: You might want to check these sites too.
iforce2d.net - Although it's for Box2d, you can learn a lot from this site.